# Why am I getting the error "the Method Is Undefined for the type"?

Tags: java, methods, types, constructor, undefined

I am learning the basics at University and would like some help with the following error from Eclipse : "The method getCost() is undefined for the type ShopCLI" &

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The method getCost() is undefined for the type ShopCLI
    at components.ShopCLI.main(ShopCLI.java:39)
```

Here is my code

```
public class ShopCLI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Order> ord = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Welcome to Sandwich Shop CLI V1!");
        System.out.println("Please Choose and Option by Typing the Appropriate Number from the List");
        System.out.println("1.New Order");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please Choose an Outer From the List: ");
        System.out.println("Press 1 to Continue or 2 to Exit");
        int Sandwich = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Outer Options are Bun, Bread or Brioche");

        String inputOuter = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Inner Options are Ham, Cheese or Cucumber");

        String inputInner = sc.next();

        System.out.println("Sauce Options are Mayo, Butter or Marmite");

        String inputSauce = sc.next();


        if (Sandwich == 1){
            ord.add(new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0));
            System.out.println("You Made a " + inputInner + " with " + inputSauce + " Sandwich on " + inputOuter);
            System.out.println("This Will Cost " + getCost());
        }
        else if (Sandwich == 2){
            System.out.println("Exited.");
        }

    }

}

public class Sandwich {

    //Fields
    ArrayList<Sandwich> sandwich = new ArrayList<>();
    String outer;
    String inner;
    String sauce;

    //Constructor
    public Sandwich(String outer, String inner, String sauce){
        this.outer = outer;
        this.inner = inner;
        this.sauce = sauce;
    }

    //Methods

    public String getOuter(){
        return outer;
    }

    public String getInner(){
        return inner;
    }

    public String getSauce(){
        return sauce;
    }

    public void setOuter(String repOuter){
        outer = repOuter;
    }

    public void setInner(String repInner){
        inner = repInner;
    }

    public void setSauce(String repSauce){
        sauce = repSauce;
    }

    public void createSandwich(String outer, String inner, String sauce){
        sandwich.add(new Sandwich(outer, inner, sauce));
    }

    public void setSandwich(String repOuter, String repInner, String repSauce){
        outer = repOuter;
        inner = repInner;
        sauce = repSauce;
    }

    public void resetOrder(){
        sandwich.removeAll(sandwich);
    }
}

public class Order extends Sandwich {

    //Fields
    int OrderId;
    double Cost;


    //Constructor
    public Order(int OrderId, String outer, String inner, String sauce, int Cost) {
        super(outer, inner, sauce);
        this.OrderId = OrderId;
        this.Cost = Cost;

    }

    //Methods

    public int getOrderId(){
        return this.OrderId;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return this.Cost;
    }

    public void setOrderId(int repOrderID){
        this.OrderId = repOrderID;
    }

    public void overrideCost(int Cost){
        this.Cost = Cost;
    }

    public void setOrder(int repOrderId, String repOuter, String repInner, String repSauce){
        this.OrderId = repOrderId;
        this.outer = repOuter;
        this.inner = repInner;
        this.sauce = repSauce;

        double calcCost;
        double outerCost = 0;
        double innerCost = 0;
        double sauceCost = 0;

        //Outer Cost
        if(repOuter == "Bun")
        {
            outerCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(repOuter == "Bread")
        {
            outerCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(repOuter == "Brioche")
        {
            outerCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Bread Type");
        }

        //Inner cost
        if(repInner == "Ham")
        {
            innerCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(repInner == "Cheese")
        {
            innerCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(repInner == "Cucumber")
        {
            innerCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Filling Type");
        }

        //Sauce Cost
        if(repSauce == "Mayo")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(repSauce == "Butter")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(repSauce == "Marmite")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Sauce Type");
        }

        calcCost = outerCost + innerCost + sauceCost;
        this.Cost = calcCost;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getCost` method is defined in order class and not in `ShopCLI` class. So your code:

```
ord.add(new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0));
System.out.println("You Made a " + inputInner + " with " + inputSauce + " Sandwich on " + inputOuter);
System.out.println("This Will Cost " + getCost());
```

Should be changed to

```
Order order = new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0);
ord.add(order);
System.out.println("You Made a " + inputInner + " with " + inputSauce + " Sandwich on " + inputOuter);
System.out.println("This Will Cost " + order.getCost());
                                       ^^^^^
```

Comment: Still errors with: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getCost() from the type Order

 at components.ShopCLI.main(ShopCLI.java:39)

Comment: Can you paste the code you changed in your Question? Did you do the changes as mentioned above? notice i haven't used Capital O in order and i have used order instance which i created earlier if you check my answer.

Comment: I used the code correction `ord.get(0).getCost());` from below and now it compiles but the costs don't update

Comment: I have read the answer and changed it accordingly however i still receive a `getCost() = 0.0`

Comment: That's because you are passing 0 as cost for other `new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0)` see last parameter.

Comment: So how can I get it to calculate this cost rather than set the cost each time as outlined in the IF statement that calculates it for the person

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
System.out.println("This Will Cost " + getCost());
```

...you don't specify what you want to call `getCost()` on, so it calls it on ShopCLI because that's where the call is happening. But ShopCLI doesn't have a `getCost()` method. You need to call it on your order:

```
System.out.println("This Will Cost " + ord.get(0).getCost());
```

This works, but when you create your Order object by calling the constructor, you're not calculating the cost, but rather setting whatever is passed in. Update your constructor to this:

```
    //Constructor
    public Order(int OrderId, String outer, String inner, String sauce) {
        super(outer, inner, sauce);
        this.OrderId = OrderId;

        double calcCost;
        double outerCost = 0;
        double innerCost = 0;
        double sauceCost = 0;

        //Outer Cost
        if(outer == "Bun")
        {
            outerCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(outer == "Bread")
        {
            outerCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(outer == "Brioche")
        {
            outerCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Bread Type");
        }

        //Inner cost
        if(inner == "Ham")
        {
            innerCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(inner == "Cheese")
        {
            innerCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(inner == "Cucumber")
        {
            innerCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Filling Type");
        }

        //Sauce Cost
        if(sauce == "Mayo")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.5;
        }
        else if(sauce == "Butter")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.25;
        }
        else if(sauce == "Marmite")
        {
            sauceCost = 0.75;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Sauce Type");
        }

        calcCost = outerCost + innerCost + sauceCost;
        this.Cost = calcCost;

    }
```

Now your constructor works, but you will have to remove an argument where you're calling it, so change your ord.add line to this:

```
ord.add(new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce));
```

That should, if I'm not mistaken work. However, you might want to consider making a private helper method called calculateCost, so that you're not duplicating code between your constructor and your setOrder methods.

Comment: This allows it to compile (Thankyou) but now my Costs arent updating as per the massive `if()` statement. `This Will Cost 0.0` is outputted

Comment: Your massive if statement only gets called in setOrder(). Try adding the if statement to your Order constructor.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please look at it. It should explain your problem.

Comment: That answer compiles and runs but when i print the cost out it still displays 0.0 `System.out.println("This Will Cost " + ord.get(0).getCost());`

Answer (score 0):

you must get the object from the arraylist, then do acces the method:

```
//get obj,then void
System.out.println("This Will Cost " + ord.get(choise).getCost());
```

this will return 0, since you set the cost 0 in the constructor:

```
ord.add(new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0));
```

also, name your integer "Sandwich" to "sandwich" without the capital letter. otherwise, it looks like you mean the class "Sandwich"

Answer (score 0):

Create an Order

```
Order order = new Order(1, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0);
ord.add(order) // Add the order to your list.
```

The cost for an order is set by the method setOrder(int repOrderId, String repOuter, String repInner, String repSauce)

change this method to the following.

```
public void setOrder() {

    double calcCost;
    double outerCost = 0;
    double innerCost = 0;
    double sauceCost = 0;

    // Outer Cost
    if (outer.equalsIgnoreCase("Bun")) {
        outerCost = 0.5;
    } else if (outer.equalsIgnoreCase("Bread")) {
        outerCost = 0.25;
    } else if (outer.equalsIgnoreCase("Brioche")) {
        outerCost = 0.75;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Bread Type");
    }

    // Inner cost
    if (inner.equalsIgnoreCase("Ham")) {
        innerCost = 0.5;
    } else if (inner.equalsIgnoreCase("Cheese")) {
        innerCost = 0.25;
    } else if (inner.equalsIgnoreCase("Cucumber")) {
        innerCost = 0.75;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Filling Type");
    }

    // Sauce Cost
    if (sauce.equalsIgnoreCase("Mayo")) {
        sauceCost = 0.5;
    } else if (sauce.equalsIgnoreCase("Butter")) {
        sauceCost = 0.25;
    } else if (sauce.equalsIgnoreCase("Marmite")) {
        sauceCost = 0.75;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid Sauce Type");
    }

    calcCost = outerCost + innerCost + sauceCost;
    this.Cost = calcCost;
}
```

Now you can get the cost by calling the getCost() on the order as follows.

To calculate the order cost, call
    order.setOrder();
To get the order cost, call
    order.getCost();

**NOTE: Don't use == to compare string. Always use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase().**

Answer (score 0):

i have modified your code for class ShopCLI

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShopCLI {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   ArrayList<Order> ord = new ArrayList<>();
   int orderNumber =1;
   System.out.println("Welcome to Sandwich Shop CLI V1!");
   System.out.println("start order");

   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  while(true){
   System.out.println("Press 1 for new order or 2 to Exit");
   int choice = sc.nextInt();

   if (choice == 1){
     System.out.println("Enter outer Options:Outer Options are Bun, Bread or Brioche");

      String inputOuter = sc.next();

      System.out.println("Enter inner Options:Inner Options are Ham, Cheese or Cucumber");

      String inputInner = sc.next();

      System.out.println("Enter sauce Options:Sauce Options are Mayo, Butter or Marmite");

      String inputSauce = sc.next();
     Order order1 = new Order(orderNumber, inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce, 0);
     order1.setOrder(inputOuter, inputInner, inputSauce);
       System.out.println("You Made a " + inputInner + " with " + inputSauce + " Sandwich on " + inputOuter);
       System.out.println("This Will Cost " + order1.getCost());
       ord.add(order1);
   }
   else if (choice == 2){
       System.out.println("Exited.");
       System.exit(1);
   }
  }
 }

}
```

and format of `setOrder` method is modified too
`public void setOrder(String repOuter, String repInner, String repSauce)`